# Get Logo to Display For Facebook Link

Tags: wordpress

Here's the link to the site: http://510nora.com

For some reason, I cannot get the site's logo to show up in Facebook when you go to share the link. Instead, it shows three of the four page thumbnails.

I've inserted meta data. I've gotten plugin's to override settings in the theme. I've done everything that I know of and nothing is working!!!

Instead of showing the site's logo (which is in a meta tag, a featured image, AND attached to the page), it's showing three of the four thumbnails listed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook debugger shows you as having multiple `og:url`s set.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2F510nora.com

Resolve this and Facebook should be able to correctly fetch your OG tags, including your `og:image` one.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- for Facebook -->          
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
```

Just edit this with URL of your logo: `<meta property="og:image" content="" />` 
and add to head section

Comment: But not in head section

Comment: Again, look at the source. An `og:image` tag is the very first thing after the `<head>` tag. http://cl.ly/image/3z401y2B1V3O